# Can't run Laravel app on digitalocean using ngnix

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

My Laravel app is returning 404 on every route.

This is the address: http://67.205.191.11/, when I try for example http://67.205.191.11/classes, 404 not found is returned.

my nginx default config file looks as below:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/venture-backend/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name 67.205.191.11;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
```

}

Anyone knows why my routes are not working?

Comment: wrong site. please use server fault or contact me on private

Comment: @Indra didnt get you exactly what u meant, how do I contact you and why should I? Can't you just answer here?

Comment: Contact me on twitter and i'll give you my email. I can't help you here because this is server related and the question belongs here: http://serverfault.com/ or here for ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/ plus we need to debug it

Comment: @Indra how do I find you on twitter?

Comment: can't find you there, np at all. I will see if anyone else have any answer on this here on stackoverflow...